# MSBuild solution command line output to individual folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, deployment, msbuild

Currently, I have the following MSBuild command:

```
msbuild 
    /t:Build 
    /p:Configuration=Release 
    /p:OutputPath=C:\MySolutionOutput\ 
    MySolution.sln
```

Which compiles, however, I have multiple projects in my solution.  When I do a build this way with the solution file, it copies all project outputs to the same directory, and the output from Project2 overwrites the output from Project1 (or whatever order they're built in).

Instead, I want MSBuild to put each project into a subfolder of the project name.

```
msbuild 
    /t:Build 
    /p:Configuration=Release 
    /p:OutputPath=C:\MySolutionOutput\$(ProjectName)
    MySolution.sln
```

However, the `$(ProjectName)` syntax does not work as it literally makes a folder called $(ProjectName).

How do I make MSBuild solution building output each project to a subdirectory of the OutputPath, preferably without making MSBuild xml files, or building each project individually?

To illustrate further, my projects are as follows.

```
+ Project 1
    + File1.txt
    + File2.txt
    + ReadMe.txt

+ Project 2
    + File3.txt
    + File4.txt
    + ReadMe.txt
```

What my build outputs

```
C:\MySolutionOutput\File1.txt
C:\MySolutionOutput\File2.txt
C:\MySolutionOutput\File3.txt
C:\MySolutionOutput\File4.txt
C:\MySolutionOutput\ReadMe.txt 
^-- (this is the 2nd readme, project 1's readme gets overwritten)
```

What I want

```
C:\MySolutionOutput\Project 1\File1.txt
C:\MySolutionOutput\Project 1\File2.txt
C:\MySolutionOutput\Project 1\ReadMe.txt

C:\MySolutionOutput\Project 2\File3.txt
C:\MySolutionOutput\Project 2\File4.txt
C:\MySolutionOutput\Project 2\ReadMe.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When building a solution using msbuild, it internally transforms the solution into an msbuild xml file which builds all projects and passes properties like OutputPath to it, and afaik there isn't a way to interfere with how this behaves. One possible solution does require you to write msbuild files yourself, but the modifications are really minor. You don't mention which project type you're using but the principle is the same for any type, and here's a sample for C# projects:

- create a common file which allows overriding OutputPath in the way you want it, but does nothing unless specifically told to in order to keep existing behaviour if needed
- import that file in each project
- specify custom output directory on the command line

msbuild file, say `outputpath.props`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPathBaseDir)' != ''">$(OutputPathBaseDir)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

import in each project; here I am using a relative path but you could reference eg $(SolutionDir) etc; for c# projects, insert this line right before the one shown

```
<Import Project="..\outputpath.props" />
<!--the below is an existing line in every c# project-->
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

now build:

```
msbuild mysolution.sln /p:OutputPathBaseDir=C:\MySolutionOutput
```

Comment: I have a love-hate relationship with MSBuild. Whenever you want to deviate from default behaviour, there's a good chance you'll have to jump through hoops.

Comment: It was very hard to look upon a solution like this on the internet. I wonder why Microsoft haven't though about easing the build process with a solution containing more than one executable as an output. Well anyway, thank you, this was the solution we were looking for.

Comment: @DaveWut my guess: they have thought about it, and about many other things, but with such a wide userbase with so many different wishes they can not possibly implement everything while pleasing everyone. So they put in the basics which work for, let's say, 90% of users, while making sure the system is generic enough to make sure the other 10% can get what they want, though via a custom solution which is not terribly hard to implement.

Comment: @stijn I agree with you and I don't have a problem customizing my build with a configuration like this one, this is indeed really easy to implement and to use. My only problem is that I find it hard to have some official documentation about the subject on the official Microsoft web site. Maybe I misused some keywords when I searched, who knows? Anyway, thanks again for your solution! :)

Comment: @DaveWut I don't think you misused anything: the documentation on custom msbuild code like this one is just virtually non-existent (apart from an example here and there), because it is impossible to document every possible thing out there. So it makes sense you cannot finde it easily on the MS site. Luckily there is StackOverflow :] However you can get quite some insight just by looking at the (massive amount) of MSBuild files which come with VS etc.