# How can I skip $Configuration folder in output path

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I'm using the command line to build my project with msbuild. It always places the output files to "bin/$Configuration" (e.g. bin/Release) but I want the output to be just "bin" (without $Configuration). How can I achieve this?

Right now I'm building with the following command:

```
msbuild c:\projects\gameplay\b\gameplay.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:OutputPath=c:\projects\gameplay\bin
```

Comment: set the OutputPath to $(SolutionDir)..\bin ?

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the .xxproj file, change the default output path:

```
 <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>.
```

Of course, if you want to make sure that all projects have the same settings during you create them automatically, maybe you could create a custom project template which use the specific output path.

I also found the similar issue which also provide others suggestion:

[MSBuild solution command line output to individual folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191467/msbuild-solution-command-line-output-to-individual-folders)

Comment: I don't want to edit the .xxproj file (because it's being autogenerated by a custom tool). I want to run msbuild with command line options to build to the specified output folder (without Release/Debug).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify Output parameter with relative path. For example:

```
msbuild c:\projects\gameplay\b\gameplay.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:OutputPath=bin\
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Writing "/p:OutputPath=bin\" results in output being built to "bin\Release"

Comment: @jnsmalm What's the result if you build a new solution and projects through MSBuild with Output parameter? You can share the solution/projects on the OneDrive.

Comment: What do you mean with "build a new solution and projects through MSBuild"?

Comment: @jnsmalm Just create a new solution with some new projects, then build it through MSBuild tool (specify /p:outputPath argument)

Comment: @jnsmalm Could you share a simple solution on the OneDrive?